# Why is that the only the print function returns the list?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, return, printf

So I am trying to make a money flow index indicator, and so far the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

#get stock prices
start = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
d = web.DataReader('AMD', 'yahoo', start, end)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)

def Money_Flow_index(period = 5):
    d['typical_price'] = (d['High'] + d['Close'] + d['Low'])/3
    for i in reversed(range(len(d['typical_price']))):
        if i > 5:
            typical_price_dates = d['typical_price'][i-period:i]
            print(typical_price_dates)
Money_Flow_index()
```

I am relatively new to python so this is me probally not understanding something basic.. Though right now the code is trying to index out the Adj Close price of each incremental set of data for 5 periods. Therefore, when I run the code as is the output is:

```
Date
2019-12-23    45.160000
2019-12-24    46.306667
2019-12-26    46.533334
2019-12-27    46.346667
2019-12-30    45.449999
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-20    43.889999
2019-12-23    45.160000
2019-12-24    46.306667
2019-12-26    46.533334
2019-12-27    46.346667
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-19    42.923333
2019-12-20    43.889999
2019-12-23    45.160000
2019-12-24    46.306667
2019-12-26    46.533334
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-18    42.533334
2019-12-19    42.923333
2019-12-20    43.889999
2019-12-23    45.160000
2019-12-24    46.306667
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-17    42.676668
2019-12-18    42.533334
2019-12-19    42.923333
2019-12-20    43.889999
2019-12-23    45.160000
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-16    42.353333
2019-12-17    42.676668
2019-12-18    42.533334
2019-12-19    42.923333
2019-12-20    43.889999
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-13    41.720001
2019-12-16    42.353333
2019-12-17    42.676668
2019-12-18    42.533334
2019-12-19    42.923333
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-12    41.486666
2019-12-13    41.720001
2019-12-16    42.353333
2019-12-17    42.676668
2019-12-18    42.533334
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-11    39.373334
2019-12-12    41.486666
2019-12-13    41.720001
2019-12-16    42.353333
2019-12-17    42.676668
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-10    39.329999
2019-12-11    39.373334
2019-12-12    41.486666
2019-12-13    41.720001
2019-12-16    42.353333
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-09    39.226667
2019-12-10    39.329999
2019-12-11    39.373334
2019-12-12    41.486666
2019-12-13    41.720001
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-06    39.793334
2019-12-09    39.226667
2019-12-10    39.329999
2019-12-11    39.373334
2019-12-12    41.486666
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-05    39.796666
2019-12-06    39.793334
2019-12-09    39.226667
2019-12-10    39.329999
2019-12-11    39.373334
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-04    39.546666
2019-12-05    39.796666
2019-12-06    39.793334
2019-12-09    39.226667
2019-12-10    39.329999
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
Date
2019-12-03    38.326668
2019-12-04    39.546666
2019-12-05    39.796666
2019-12-06    39.793334
2019-12-09    39.226667
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
```

Which is what I am looking for, but then when I trying `return(typical_price_dates)` it only prints the first set:

```
Date
2019-12-23    45.160000
2019-12-24    46.306667
2019-12-26    46.533334
2019-12-27    46.346667
2019-12-30    45.449999
Name: typical_price, dtype: float64
```

The issue with this is when I try to access `typical_price_dates`, it only shows the first series rather than all of the series. For example if I wanted to do something like:

```
typical_price = typical_price_dates
typical_volume = d['Volume']
d['money_flow_index'] = typical_price * typical_volume
```

It only access the first series. So basicaly how can I make it so that the variable typical_price_dates is equal to all the series not just one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use return in your code, the loop runs for only  **one** time and return the result and you come out of the function and no loop runs after that, what you should do is append **typical_price_dates** each time to something like a **python list** , like this

```
z=[]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

#get stock prices
start = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
d = web.DataReader('AMD', 'yahoo', start, end)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)

def Money_Flow_index(period = 5):
    d['typical_price'] = (d['High'] + d['Close'] + d['Low'])/3
    for i in reversed(range(len(d['typical_price']))):
        if i > 5:
            typical_price_dates = d['typical_price'][i-period:i]
            z.append(typical_price_dates)
Money_Flow_index()

for i in z:
    print(i)
```